# Ruby versions and rails version on site5 is old

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I m working on a project which was developed by another developer. Right now my job is to fix the bugs and all the necessary things. After all those things successfully done when i started to work for deployment on `site5.com` i got to know [here](http://www.site5.com/blog/programming/ruby-rails/) that they ve not upgraded the ruby version. Still they are using ruby 1.8.7. There is a tutorial to upgrade the system to rails 3 but m not able to do that. The rails version installed on the server is 2.3.16.
When the code was given to me i `bundle installed` it with new version `1.9.3` and then i fixed few bugs which was a syntax error because of that syntax deprecation in `1.9.3`. Now i ve asked to the client that there may be some compatibility issues if i go with the installation. Now what should i do? Should i go with the installation or suggest him some other hosting website.

Answer (score 0):

since phusion 4 is stable now (allowing multiple rubies), and ruby 1.8 is considered 'legacy' by phusion developers (see [their blog](http://blog.phusion.nl/)), doing any fixes for ruby 1.8.x seems to be a waste of time.

Changing ruby version requirements would break the application on `site5`, if they're really still on 1.8.x .